# How to make htaccess rule not affect directory?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder called min and i have a htacces in it that handles non-existing paths like /min/variable to return some data.

Now in the main folder i put a htaccess with contents like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?emit/(.*)$ emit.php?nice=t&f=$1
```

Unfortunately now after i call domain.com/min/variable i get empty website.

How to fix it so that the new rule will not block the old one? Something like:

```
if something from /min/ is called don't use the new rule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do that in the way you want.

Simply make .htaccess file in your dir and put there "RewriteEngine off" statement.

But it will turn off all your statements